# How to listen to user audio in google actions / assistant console?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am using dialogflow to create a google assistant app. I want to hear what the user said for error resolving. How can I do that? I know it is possible in Alexa but I cannot find it on Google.

Answer (score 1):

Developers do not get access to the user's original audio clips, just the transcriptions. If you are detecting a number of errors from your action, it may be useful to try to get a better understanding of how users are conversing with your actions in general.

Comment: Is there any method to get the time the user spent on speaking the sentence?

Comment: No, information about the user's audio is not provided directly nor through metadata about the audio.